# How to generate protobuf 3.0 jar java?

Tags: java, eclipse, protocol-buffers

I am quiet familiar with protobuf 2.5. I was trying to use protobuf3.0. It seems that the jar is to be generated form the source code available online. But when i import the source code into eclipse and try to create a jar, i can see many errors in the following files

```
/protobuf3/src/com/google/protobuf/Descriptors.java,
/protobuf3/src/com/google/protobuf/DynamicMessage.java
/protobuf3/src/com/google/protobuf/ExtensionRegistry.java
/protobuf3/src/com/google/protobuf/MessageReflection.java
/protobuf3/src/com/google/protobuf/TextFormat.java
/protobuf3/src/com/google/protobuf/UnsafeUtil.java
```

This is one of the errors "the import com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos cannot be resolved".

Is this the right way to generate the jar (or) is it available anywhere (or) is the full source code available anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

This is where i downloaded the source code [protobuf3.0-source code](https://github.com/google/protobuf/archive/v3.0.0.zip)

Comment: To build the Java protobuf library you could follow the steps in the repository `https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/java`.

Comment: **Thanks**. It worked...

Answer (score 3):

You can find a compiled (JAR) version of Protobuf to download here:

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.0.0/protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar

I recommend you look at a build manager such as https://maven.apache.org/ to automatically handle fetching dependencies (libraries) for you.